# How can I enable Run terminal Output on PyCharm 2017.1

Tags: python, pycharm

Since I upgraded PyCharm from 2016.3.3 to the latest 2017.1 the Run terminal Output is not displaying as my scrip runs from beginning to end. Instead the output on the terminal is shown at the very end once the test script completes running.

Can I adjust the Run Terminal to display text/output as the script is running instead of having it all displayed at the end in the latest version of PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

Known issue in Pycharm, see link to view the bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22505